# Using Offline.js in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a hard time to make use of the [Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/) in NodeJS. I've used the Offline.js like the following but it always shows `check()` is undefined or any other methods.

```js
import Offline from 'offline-js'

Offline.options = {
  checkOnLoad: true,
  checks: {
    xhr: {
      url: 'http://google.com'
    }
  }
}

Offline.check()

Offline.Offline.on('up', () => {
  alert('Up')
})

Offline.Offline.down('down', () => {
  alert('Down')
})
```

Comment: Offline.js works by intercepting AJAX requests which only works (out of the box) in browsers. You'll need to find or create another solution for the server-side.

Comment: I'm using this on an Electron app and used it on the Render process. So, I think should works. But, while compiling, the Webpack shows, `check()`, `on()` are undefined

Comment: For Node.js, there's [`is-online`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online).

Comment: Yeah, I have played with this as well but the is-online doesn't have a watcher. I'd have to manually set a `setTimeout()` function that may cause app performance issue.

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan Is `Offline` undefined? It's possible that it isn't available as a module. You could try loading it using a plain old script tag and access it as a global variable.

Comment: @MikeC yeah you're right, it's not a module, it's really meant to be loaded using `<script>`.

Comment: That's the strange part. The `Offline` isn't undefined. The console shows `Offline` is an object as expected.

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan have you seen [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/online-offline-events.md)?

Comment: @robertklep I did. That's not the solution as the Electron native offline check shows true even when you have an active Lan connection. On the other hand, when I saw the Offline.js in the npmjs.com, I was confused and still why the Offline.js won't work then as a Node module. Any clue about this?

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan It looks like the author of it doesn't really understand how modules are supposed to work. Either way, [it looks like other people have had trouble using it in Electron.](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline/issues/223) Without digging in to the source and debugging it directly, I'm not sure how much help we can be. You could try contacting the author of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with the following solution using the [isOnline package].[1](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online/) as [Offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline) doesn't work in Node or on the server side.

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
  isOnline({timeout: 1000}).then(online => {
    if (!online) {
      this.online = false
    }
  })
})

window.addEventListener('online', () => {
  isOnline({timeout: 1000}).then(online => {
    if (online) {
      this.online = true
    }
  })
})

isOnline({timeout: 1000}).then(online => {
  if (!online) {
    this.online = false
  }
})
```

The `isOnline()` method on the last part was used because once the Electron app starts and if there is no Lan or Wifi connection, the `window. addEventListener('offline')` doesn't fire. I added the event under the Vue `mounted()` method. So, I had to use the `isOnline()` method again outside of the `window.addEventListener()` event.